# greping a character from file UNIX.linux bash. Can't pass an argument(file name) through command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, parameters

I am having trouble with my newbie linux script which needs to count brackets and tell if they are matched.

```
#!/bin/bash

    file="$1"
    x="()(((a)(()))"
    left=$(grep -o "(" <<<"$x" | wc -l) 
    rght=$(grep -o ")" <<<"$x" | wc -l)

    echo "left = $left right = $rght"
    if [ $left -gt $rght ]
       then echo "not enough brackets"
    elif [ $left -eq $rght ]
       then echo "all brackets are fine"
    else echo "too many" 
    fi
```

the problem here is i can't pass an argument through command line so that grep would work and count the brackets from the file. In the $x place I tried writing $file but it does not work

I am executing the script by writting: ./script.h test1.txt the file test1.txt is on the same folder as script.h

Any help in explaining how the parameter passing works would be great. Or maybe other way to do this script?

Comment: What command line are you trying?

Comment: "I am executing the script by writting: ./script.h test1.txt the file test1.txt is on the same folder as script.h" as written before. I am connecting through putty to my Uni linux server. and compiling the script throught that terminal if that was your question.

Comment: But where are you using `$file` in your script above?

Comment: instead of $x.. $x i used for testing purposes to see if it works.

Comment: ok what's the problem in using `left=$(grep -o "(" "$file" | wc -l)`

Comment: Your scripts works fine on my machine (RH 5.6) / BASH and it gives the expected results. If your test1.txt file exists then, do a "set -x" (just before file="$1" line) and "set +x" (just after file="$1" line).. and run the script, this will at least show you if file variable is getting $1 correctly or not. file variable in your script is redundant at the moment.

Comment: Did not manage to get this working this way. Instead what i did was: file_cont=$(cat $file)
and then left=$(grep -o "(" <<<"$file_cont" | wc -l) 
rght=$(grep -o ")" <<<"$file_cont" | wc -l)       This way it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construct `<<<` is used to transmit "the contents of a variable", It is not applicable to "contents of files". If you execute this snippet, you could see what I mean:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="()(((a)((a simple test)))"
echo "$( cat <<<"$file" )"
```

which is also equivalent to just `echo "$file"`. That is, what is being sent to the console are the contents of the variable "file".

To get the "contents of a file" which name is inside a var called "file", then do:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="test1.txt"
echo "$( cat <"$file" )"
```

which is exactly equivalent to `echo "$( <"$file" )"`, `cat <"$file"` or even `<"$file" cat` 
You can use: `grep -o "(" <"$file"` or `<"$file" grep -o "("`
But grep could accept a file as a parameter, so this: `grep -o "(" "$file"` also works.

However, I believe that `tr` would be a better command, as this: `<"$file" tr -cd "("`.
It transforms the whole file into a sequence of "(" only, which will need a lot less to be transmitted (passed) to the `wc` command. Your script would become, then:

```
#!/bin/bash -
file="$1"

[[    $file ]] || exit 1    # make sure the var "file" is not empty.
[[ -r $file ]] || exit 2    # test if the file "file" exists.

left=$(<"$file" tr -cd "("| wc -c) 
rght=$(<"$file" tr -cd ")"| wc -c)

echo "left = $left right = $rght"

# as $left and $rght are strictly numeric values, this integer tests work:
(( $left >  $rght )) && echo "not enough right brackets"
(( $left == $rght )) && echo "all brackets are fine"
(( $left <  $rght )) && echo "too many right brackets"

# added as per an additional request of the OP.
if [[ $(<"$file" tr -cd "()"|head -c1) = ")" ]]; then 
    echo "the first character is (incorrectly) a right bracket"
fi
```

Comment: What i did realise is that the script is not working if for example the file inside has: ) ( ()
It will show that all brackets are fine although the first bracket is a closing bracket. Can I check the text file for the first bracket and if it is a closing bracket to echo an error and stop executing a script?